# monitor is going to sleep

Tags: display, sleep

i have two windows 7 manchines that are saying monitor is going to sleep when i turn them on.  the light on the monitor turns green and i have to press it and is saying that there is no video connection from the computer.  i plugged another computer into the same monitor(s) i have two and was able to remote my pc.  any suggestions?

i tried a different monitor with no luck and tried running updates today on my computer with no luck.  there aren't any viruses on the machine.

Comment: i also tried getting into the bios and the safe mode menu without success.

Comment: How did you run updates if you couldn't see anything on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either your video cable is faulty or your graphics card has broken down. You already plugged a different computer into the monitor without a problem, so it isn't the monitor.

Try replacing the video cable with one that's known to work (that is, a video cable that works on another PC). If that fixes the problem, you need a new video cable.

If it doesn't work, then the problem has to be your graphics card: you will probably need a new one.